# @font-face faux-italic in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, font-face

I have been following the hopefully bulletproof instructions for @font-face in this article http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/02/14/setting-weights-and-styles-at-font-face-declaration/comment-page-1/#comment-870111

Unfortunately I am still getting faux-italicisation in IE8 on my webfonts, as I attempt to account for the styling of my fall-back fonts if the font doesn't load for some reason.

I am using Pacifico script font (served locally), and I want to make sure it degrades to serif italic. I sneakily have declared it as font-style:italic in my @font-face.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Pacifico';
src: url('Pacifico-webfont.eot');
src: url('Pacifico-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('Pacifico-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('Pacifico-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('Pacifico-webfont.svg#Pacifico') format('svg');
font-weight: 500;
font-style: italic;

}
```

This h1 style loads the font correctly, but in IE8, the script gets faux-italic.

```
 h1{
font-family: 'Pacifico', serif;
font-weight: 500;
font-style: italic;
font-size: 32px;
color: #f9a51a;
```

Pretty sure I have followed all instructions correctly :(. All works as expected in Chrome and Firefox - the @font-face declaration I have done does indeed stop the faux-styling. But I fear there is no perfect solution for IE8.

(to clarify - IE9 seems to renders both webfont and fall-back font/style correctly.)

Comment: Why are you using `font-weight: 500`? It is practically certain that the font denoted by the generic name `serif` does not have any typeface with that weight, so a browser should use weight 400 instead, but why give them a chance to fail with this?

Comment: is that the only font-face declaration you are using? if not, i may know an answer. but i agree with @jukka you should be serving that up as font-weight:400

Comment: Thanks for your replies, sorry for my delayed acknowledgement. I did change this to 400, if this is more semantic. but it hasn't made any difference to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This font has [issues with acute characters](https://code.google.com/p/googlefontdirectory/issues/detail?id=209). It took me several days to track down the bug in my css, to finally find out it was the webfont. It kept switching on compatibility view in IE8, or crashing IETester.

Sadly the only fix is to use another font, until the font author updates it and fixes the issue.